# The phone won't receive some text messages (Specially the verification codes from Google, Dropbox, Evernote, etc)

Tags: sms, 4.4-kitkat, samsung, samsung-galaxy-note

Recently, my phone stopped receiving verification text messages from Google, Dropbox and Evernote. I contacted the carrier and they say on their end things are working (My other phone (same carrier) receives these messages). I can receive other messages from my friends. I even reset my phone. Still not working? Is it something to do with Android? My phone is Glaxy Note 3 with Kitkat 4.4.3.

Comment: After the reset (I assume you're talking about a [factory-reset](http://android.stackexchange.com/tags/factory-reset/info) here?), did you re-install any of your apps, or did you first check in "plain state"? One of your apps might be intercepting (and "eating") those messages.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have avg anti-virus installed on your device? If yes he might be the guy not letting through these short number messages